# How to input 2d array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make a 2d array that will have 3 rows and 4 columns. I am a total beginner and I'm not sure if I should inport math or numpy to do this. I tried searching online but it's pretty confusing.
name of the 2d array is grid2 and this is what I came up with:

```
grid2 = []
rows = 3
col = 4

for i in range(0,rows):
    for j in range(0,col):
        eleG = int(input("Add a number: "))
        grid2.append(eleG)

print(gird2)
```

but I am getting an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Zadatak.py", line 25, in 
print(gird2)
NameError: name 'gird2' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelt the variable name 'grid2' as 'gird2'

As far as a matrix is concerned, a short, simple way would be to declare a zero 2D array and then loop in the elements as:

```
grid2 = np.zeros((rows, col))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(col):
        grid2[i][j] = int(input("Add a number: ")

print(grid2)
```

Comment: indeed he has, but he also made a 1d array instead of 2d

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with or without numpy.

without numpy:

```
matrix = []

for row in range(3):
    matrix.append([])
    for col in range(4):
        matrix[row].append(1)
```

with numpy:

```
matrix = np.ones((3,4))
```

I just filled everything with 1 but you can change it to whatever you need :)

Comment: How can I make that array actually look 2 dimensional when being printed?
so that every row is printed one bellow another

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled grid. That says "GIRD" instead of "grid". I think that's it.

Comment: they also made it 1d which i think is not what they are looking for

Comment: Hi This kind of comments can be posted as "comments" and not as answers I think.

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it it would append rows * columns records to one dimensional table.

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(0,rows): 
    grid2.append([]) #append empty list for every row
    for j in range(0,columns):
        grid2[i].append(int(input("Add a number: "))) #append new item to current row
```